# Can a relative clause introduced by a noun phrase marked by the indefinite article be both non-restrictive and restrictive?

Tags: relative-clauses, non-restrictive

> [Example 1] The quirky scientist is shot and killed by a group of Libyan terrorists **from whom he stole the plutonium that powers his new design**.

In the above example, I have used a restrictive relative clause to specify the 'Libyan terrorists' in question. (This is a piece of writing related to Back to the Future, for those interested.) However, having thought about it, I think that it would make as much sense to change the relative clause so that it becomes non-restrictive.

> [Example 2] The quirky scientist is shot and killed by a group of Libyan terrorists, **from whom he stole the plutonium that powers his new design**.

The addition of a comma in Example 2 doesn't seem to alter the conveyed meaning. As 'Libyan terrorists' is non-specific (not introduced by the definite article, 'the'), the information doesn't change the reader's understanding of the terrorists. They don't need to know that 'he' (Doc) stole plutonium from them; this is simply added information.

That said, I repeat my question from the title: can a relative clause introduced by a noun phrase marked by the indefinite article be both non-restrictive and restrictive?

Comment: I suppose purists would say that in (1) 'The quirky scientist is shot and killed by a group of Libyan terrorists from whom he stole the plutonium that powers his new design' the relative clause is defining (s/he is killed by one of groups A, B and F, from each of whom he had stolen Pu) but in (2) 'The quirky scientist is shot and killed by a group of Libyan terrorists, from whom he stole the plutonium that powers his new design' the relative clause is non-defining, and does not mandate several groups. I'd put in a comma anyway if I were forced at gunpoint to use and read out such a long ...

Comment: sentence. 'The quirky scientist is shot and killed by a group of Libyan terrorists, one from whom he stole the plutonium that powers his new design' strongly suggests (at least) that the ex-relative-clause is now again defining (in perhaps a different way: no need for groups A, B and F, from each of whom he had stolen Pu).

Comment: There's no reason why your first example should be unacceptable. There's no rule saying that an indefinite NP cannot have an integrated relative as modifier.

Comment: Well, there probly is, somewhere, in some textbook. But it's wrong.

Comment: In my head, there seems to be two possible interpretations: One is that the indefinite article indicates a greater number of terrorists who have been robbed, which would therefore make the lack of a comma strange. The second is that the indefinite article indicates a new element that the reader has not yet been made aware of, so the absence of a comma is merely specifying the significance of this particular group. If we changed the article to 'the', the reader might think that they missed a mention of the terrorists.

Comment: There is no problem with relative clauses modifying noun phrases with indefinite articles.  "A man that I know" / "A man who(m) I know" / "A man I know". Or "a problem I had", "a book I read", "An SE post I read" etc, etc.